# Por que no me toma el css que le di a la etiqueta a?

Tags: html, css, scss

No me deja cambiar el color de a. en la foto que subi se ve que no cambia el color. Ya ni me doy cuenta en que me equivoco

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  color: blanchedalmond;
}

header label {
  display: none;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
}

header label:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.637);
}

header .menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  /*al ser display flex hace que por defecto los li que esten dentro sean una caja flexible y por defecto coloque en fila*/
}

header .menu ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  text-align: right;
  color: blanchedalmond;
  text-decoration: none;
}

header .menu ul li a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.637);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <input type="checkbox" id="btn-menu">
  <label for="btn-menu"> <img src="imagenes/lista.png" alt="icono-menu"></label>
  <nav class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="index.html"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="menu.html"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="pedidos.html"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="contactos.html"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="nosotros.html"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="ubicacion.html"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </nav>


</header>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar mejor qué está pasando? No se te entiende.

Comment: ¿O quizás confundiste la propiedad `color` con `background-color`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es obvio que no se puede colorear la etiqueta `a` porque no contiene nada de texto. Agregale texto y ya está:

```css
header {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
    color: blanchedalmond;
}

header label {
    display: none;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
}

header label:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.637);
}

header .menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    /*al ser display flex hace que por defecto los li que esten dentro sean una caja flexible y por defecto coloque en fila*/
}

header .menu ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    text-align: right;
    color: blue;
    background: lightblue;
    text-decoration: none;
}

header .menu ul li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.637);
}
```

```html
<header>
   <input type="checkbox" id="btn-menu">
   <label for="btn-menu"> <img src="imagenes/lista.png" alt="icono-menu"></label>
    <nav class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Inicio</a></li>      
        <li><a href="menu.html">Menu</a></li>      
        <li><a href="pedidos.html">Pedidos</a></li>
        <li><a href="contactos.html">Contactos</a></li>
        <li><a href="nosotros.html">Nosotros</a></li>
        <li><a href="ubicacion.html">Ubicación</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
 </header>
```